# In Script#, how can one enumerate a list that one inherits from?

Tags: c#, script#

In this example:

```
abstract class MyList<T>: List<T>
{
    public T Find(int? id)
    {
        foreach(T obj in this)
        {
            if(Compare(id, obj))
                return obj;
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    protected abstract bool Compare(int? id, T obj);
}
```

I get the error

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type `LearningScriptSharp.MyList<T>` because `LearningScriptSharp.MyList<T>` does not contain a public definition for `GetEnumerator`.

How can I enumerate this list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, apparently one can't define a generic type in Script#... compiler fails, without error messages.

So I'm going to go with this, unless anyone has a better suggestion:

```
abstract class MyList
{
    private List<Object> innerList = new List<Object>();

    public Object Find(int? id)
    {
        foreach(Object obj in innerList)
        {
            if(Compare(id, obj))
                return obj;
        }
        return default(Object);
    }

    protected abstract bool Compare(int? id, Object obj);
}
```